# Set default time for datetime field odoo 11

Tags: datetime, time, odoo, default, odoo-11

I am working on odoo11 survey module.

I am assigning deadline from survey wizard  and wizard contains only date field as deadline. whereas in Answers deadline field is datetime and its show 5:30 default time value.

*My requirement*:  I want to show default time for deadline field in Answers is 23:59.

*Try*:

```
deadline = fields.Datetime('Deadline', help="Date by which the person can open the survey and submit answers",oldname="date_deadline", default=lambda *a: time.strftime('23:59:59'))
```

But  its  not  worked.

Thanks  in  advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot assign just a time to Datetime field. You can specify default value to be specific datetime or current date with specified time.

For example:

```py
from odoo import fields

deadline = fields.Datetime('Deadline', oldname="date_deadline", default='2021-02-08 23:59:59')
```

or

```py
from odoo import fields
from datetime import datetime

deadline = fields.Datetime('Deadline', oldname="date_deadline", default=lambda self: fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.now().replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)))
```