# Set time default in Datetime odoo 11

Tags: datetime, time, replace, odoo, odoo-11

I my trying to set default time in odoo create function get below error:

**TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments**

*Code:*

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    if 'deadline' in values:
        values['deadline'].replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999)
    line = super(SurveyUserInputInherit, self).create(values)    
    return line
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how's that related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68710551/10197418) with the exact same title?

Comment: Both are my question with different type of workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo stores datetime fields as string. So if you want to replace time in `create` function you need to convert it to datetime first. You can do it with function `fields.Datetime.from_string` and then again convert it to string, with `fields.Datetime.to_string` or just `str`

So in your case, this should do it:

```py
from odoo import fields

@api.model
def create(self, values):
    if 'deadline' in values:
        deadline = fields.Datetime.from_string(values['deadline'])
        deadline = deadline.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)
        values['deadline'] = fields.Datetime.to_string(deadline)
    line = super(SurveyUserInputInherit, self).create(values)    
    return line
```

Btw odoo doesn't store microsecond so it is unnecessary to replace.